# windows 8 wcf web service (localhost/intranet)

Tags: javascript, wcf, web-services, windows-8

I am trying to call a web service from an metro application. I am developing the app with javascript and the webservice is wcf-based.

I tried it like this:

```
function callWCF() {
WinJS.xhr({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://lei-023880-ws.sinternal.de:8732/sdata/myApp/myContract/-/employees",
}).done(
function (result) {
    console.log(result.responseText)       
},
function (request) {
}
);}
```

or like this:

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", "http://lei-023880-ws.s.de:8732/sdata/myApp/myContract/-/$schema", true);
        xhr.responseType = "text";
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == xhr.DONE) {
                var blob = xhr.reponse;
                window.console.log(blob);
            }
        }
        xhr.send();
```

All im getting back is an network-error with code: 2efd. I googled it. Its an "Internet_cannot_connect"-error. When im changing the url to "microsoft.com" it works fine. So i guess the problem lies with the wcf-service?
When calling the URL in windows 8- browser it also works.
Why is the app not able to call the url?

Thanks in advance.

robidd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since microsoft.com works, it sounds like the internet connectivity option has been set in the manifest?  (Not trying to be Captain Obvious :), but I've overlooked that a few times!)

You might try Fiddler and see how far the request is going - if at all. Fiddler with Windows 8 is tricky, but this post should help you set it up: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2011/09/14/fiddler-and-windows-8-metro-style-applications-https-and-private-network-capabilities.aspx

Comment: Yes internet is set. I installed Fiddler and this additional tool, but i havent changed any code and suddenly it works. Weird... thanks for your help

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem.  The app is only able to connect to my service when Fiddler is open.  My guess is that it is able to connect to Fiddler, and fiddler, as a desktop app, does not have the same restrictions on it as start menu apps.